# Reclaim tool confirmation

Tags: address, hashing

To be clear each of the hashes that are given, during the reclaim process, point to an address in a tangle explorer. This address isn't of the new seed, but actually a hash of the new seeds address even though its listed under address in the explorer? Also, is there no way of confirming that the reclaim will actually go to the new seed that was entered, after using the tool?

Comment: when you know the new seed/address, you can hash it to verify that it is correct. But there is no way when enumerating all claim transactions to get the address they will go to (or even the seed they are from) except for the IOTA foundation who have the private key to decrypt the claims.